# Automatically insert data into Word-Templates

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, templates

Word-Templates often consist of Content-Control Boxes and I wonder if it is possible to store some data like my adress or phone number in Word to automatically insert it into the respecting boxes and therefore avoid redundancy in filling these templates out.

The same is done with the Author-Name in most of the Templates.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the template and put your data in the fields that you don't need to change.